# Android Hilt - Shared ViewModel between two Fragments

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm using Jetpack Navigation and Hilt in my project and I want to share ViewModel between only two Fragments, like this:

- Fragment A: use ViewModel A
- In Fragment A navigate to Fragment B: use ViewModel B
- In Fragment B navigate to Fragment C: use instance of ViewModel B
- If from C back to B, back to A then ViewModel B will be destroyed.

How to config ViewModel B like that?

UPDATE: I found a way to use Hilt Custom Scope, but I don't know how to implement it yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `activityViewModels()` with the ViewModel following the host activity's lifecycle.

```
class BFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the activityViewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the
    // fragment-ktx artifact to retrieve the ViewModel in the activity scope
    private val viewModel: BViewModel by activityViewModels()
}

class CFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: CViewModel by viewModels()
    
    private val shareViewModel: BViewModel by activityViewModels()
}
```

Or if fragment C is a child fragment of B, you can customize the viewmodel's lifecycle as follows:

```
class BFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the fragment-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel
    private val viewModel: BViewModel by viewModels()
}

class CFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the fragment-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel using the parent fragment's scope
    private val shareViewModel: BViewModel by viewModels({requireParentFragment()})

    private val viewModel: CViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

More information: [Communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate?authuser=3#fragments)

Comment: I think this is not suitable. When I from Fragment A navigate to B, I want ViewModel B has new instance. With your way, ViewModel B is not cleared when Fragment B fall into onDestroy().

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this without a navigation graph?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `navGraphViewModels`. Create a nested graph with Fragment B & C, both will share the same `navGraphViewModel`

```
<navigation android:id="@+id/nav_graph_a"
      app:startDestination="@id/dest_a">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/dest_a"/>

    <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_graph_b_c"                  
        app:startDestination="@id/dest_b">

       <fragment android:id="@+id/dest_b"/>
       <fragment android:id="@+id/dest_c"/>

    </navigation>               
 
 </navigation>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic

https://medium.com/sprinthub/a-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-use-nav-graph-scoped-viewmodels-cf82de4545ed

Comment: I also found this Docs, but Is there a way to not use to navigation? Thank you.